# Selecting and aggregating multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns several rows that I'd like to group by a column. So for example,

```
title  | label
--------------
may      ny
may      ct
june     ma
june     ri
```

How would I (efficiently) return

```
title  | label
--------------
may      ct,ny
june     ma,ri
```

such that the ordering of the concatenation is alphabetical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function. The query would be:

```
SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(label ORDER BY label)
GROUP BY title
```